# Java - List of objects overwriting entrys

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist, overwrite

i started learning a bit more about Java and got stuck here : 
Wanted to make Objects that contain value, index and a rest and in main method a list of objects. 
By adding new objects to the list the previous entry gets overwritten.

Here is my code so far :

```
    public class LNGHW {

        public static int value;
        public static int index;
        public static int rest;

        public LNGHW(int val, int index, int mod) {
            this.value = val;
            this.index = index;
            this.rest = mod;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<LNGHW> items = new ArrayList<LNGHW>();

            items.add(new LNGHW(4, 0, 1));
            items.add(new LNGHW(2, 1, 1));

            System.out.println(items.get(0).getValue());
            System.out.println(items.get(1).getValue());
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public static void setValue(int value) {
            LNGHW.value = value;
        }

        public static int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public static void setIndex(int index) {
            LNGHW.index = index;
        }

        public static int getRest() {
            return rest;
        }

        public static void setRest(int rest) {
            LNGHW.rest = rest;
        }
   }
```

I am open for every kind of help!

Comment: your fields are _static_ hence the behavior. remove the _static_ modifiers from the fields as well the getters/setters and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

 class LNGHW {
public  int value; /*made them  non-static*/
public  int index;
public  int rest;

public LNGHW(int val, int index, int mod) {
    this.value = val;
    this.index = index;
    this.rest = mod;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<LNGHW> items = new ArrayList<LNGHW>();

    items.add(new LNGHW(4, 0, 1));
    items.add(new LNGHW(2, 1, 1));

    System.out.println(items.get(0).getValue());
    System.out.println(items.get(1).getValue());
}

public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {      /*made these values non-static*/
    this.value = value;          /*set the values of object using **this**,not class name */
}

public int getIndex() {
    return this.index;
}

public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}

public int getRest() {
    return this.rest;
}

public  void setRest(int rest) {
    this.rest = rest;
}}
```

To understand why it was happening you need to understand about **static**,**non-static** and **this** keyword in java. Please study about them and then you can understand the difference.

**STATIC**--when we want any property to be same for every object of a class then we use static keyword. For eg- suppose there is a **MAN** class and there are few attributes such as **age**,**gender** etc, then age will be different for different objects of man class i.e. **age** attribute is a object level property hence it will be non-static. whereas **gender** of every object of the **MAN** class will be male,hence it is a class level property and therefore it should be static.

Finally whenever there is a class level property we use static variables otherwise for object level property we use non-static variables.

we use **this** keyword to refer non-static variables where as **class name** for referring static variables.